# Ubuntu server installation via USB drive - Failed to load preconfiguration file, after manually mounting cdrom/USB

Tags: 16.04, server, system-installation

I've been searching on google for a while. I haven't found anything useful.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server with the image ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso via a USB hard drive. Mount the drive to `/cdrom` by running command `mount /dev/sda1 /cdrom`. When the installer failed to mount the drive automatically, I got the error:

```
Failed to retrieve the preconfiguration file
The file needed for preconfiguration could not be retrieved from file:///cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed. The installation will proceed in non-automated mode.
```

Seaming that the ISO doesn't contain a "preseed" directory. Am I missing something?
I'm no genius when it comes to Linux, so any help would be appropriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first please check with **md5sum** that your downloaded iso file is good. See this link and links from it

[help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

You can use a **tool** to install the iso file into a USB drive to make it a USB boot drive. If you are running linux, you can use **mkusb**. If you are running Windows, you can use **Win32 Disk Imager**.

These are cloning tools, and the cloning method works with all current Ubuntu and Ubuntu family iso files (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu including Ubuntu Server). But the target drive will be overwritten, so if you store some important files there, you had better copy them to a safer place before you start.

See the following links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)